# How should I get the original comment while processing the reply

Tags: comments

I'm working on a comments section for my template. And I need to do something like this:

**Comment:**
  *-This was my original comment*
And this is my reply to the original comment.



So I wanna cite the original comment inside the comment that was a reply to the original comment. I `var_dump`ed through everything that `get_the_comment();` returns and failed to find any reference to the initial comment whatsoever.

Can you please assist me with that? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The comment/reply ID is a value actually sent by the form. You are able to retrieve it via `$_GET`:

```
// Default is "no reply" eq. 0
$id = 0;
// Handle replies
if ( isset( $_GET['replytocom'] ) )
{
    $id = filter_var(
        $_GET['replytocom'],
        FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        # or:
        # FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
        array(
            'options' => array(
                'min_range' => 1,
            ),
            # @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php
            # 'flags'   => '',
        )
    );
    if ( FALSE === $id )
        break;

    $id = absint( $_GET['replytocom'] )
}
```

Then you have access to the reply-`$id`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! You mean I should put it in the reply comment's `<textarea>` the original comment? Is this your solution?

Comment: @LoomyBear I don't know how you exactly set up your comments and the comment reply task. The answer just shows from _where_ you can retrieve the ID.

Comment: sorry my bad! I've just carefully searched through the comments DB fields once again and found `comment_parent` field, which contains the reply ID. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: @LoomyBear Then please add this as separate answer. You might also want to edit your question and show a bit more of your setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad!

I've looked through what `get_comments();` returns and I found `comment_parent` field which contains the ID of the initial comment. So in order to add cite of the comment you wanna reply to you need to do the following:

```
<?php
    $pid = get_the_id();            
    $comments = get_comments('post_id='.$pid);

    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {         
        $cpid = $comment->comment_parent; // Getting the ID of the parent comment
        $comment_parent = get_comment( $cpid );

        // Do comment rendering here
        ...
    }
?>
```

Sorry for bothering everyone. I hope this would help somebody in the future.
Cheers!